# Scrollable Views Interacting with other child views like Google street View

Tags: java, android

I intend achieving a layout similar to what is shown.

[image: this]

I have tried achieving similar behavior with Bottom sheet, percentFrameLayout, ScrollView and Coordinated layout on different occasions, but I've not being able to achieve something similar to the view that (possibly a fragment) that is scroll from the bottom of the screen and interact with other child views on the screen like the tab and the refresh button.

Any guideline and directions on how i can do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a RecyclerView for the cards and leave your toolbar and main content on a FrameLayout at the same level as the map. And of course a coordinator layout and proper behaviors on each element.
By doing this your recycler view will be able to interact with the toolbar and still be independent from the map.

In other words, you can reduce your problem to a single recyclerview scroll with a toolbar by making a space on the beginning of the vertical recyclerView.